How does a single-pole-powered ADC measure signals below ground level?
In the process of researching the documentation for the MCP3914 chip, I had a question about the possibility of measuring negative voltages. The reference voltage generated inside the chip is +1.2 volts w.r.t AGND. There is also no need to supply a negative supply voltage. However, the chip allows you to supply a signal to its inputs in the range from -1 to 1 volt. This may indicate the presence of a complex negative voltage generation circuit inside the chip? How does it measure the negative voltage?
MCP3914 Docs ref link

From the Microchip MCP3914 documentation I can't see a definitive statement about how  the chip allows negative voltages to be sampled with only a unipolar AVDD supply.
The only hint from the datasheet is the following in section 4.19 ADC Reset Mode:

If MCLK is not applied, large analog input leakage currents can be observed for highly negative input voltages (typically below -0.6V, referred to as AGND).

Which suggests that perhaps MCLK is used to drive a negative voltage generation circuit inside the MCP3914.
Looking at the TI ADS131M04 4-Channel, Simultaneously-Sampling, 24-Bit, Delta-Sigma ADC which is a similar product, the datasheet contains:

The analog power supply (AVDD – AGND) can
operate between 2.7 V and 3.6 V. An integrated negative charge pump allows absolute input voltages as low as 1.3 V below AGND, which enables measurements of input signals varying around ground with a single-ended power supply.

Therefore, my guess is that like the TI ADS131M04, the Microchip MCP3914 internally contains a charge pump to allow negative input voltages to be connected to the inputs.

You have to wonder how accurate that negative charge pump is, then.
